# Django Wrong form submitted using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms

I'm implementing a simple exercise to teach cryptography methods. Currently Im working with the Caesar Cipher. The web app works as follow, user enters a key and plaintext to generate a dynamically form containing each letter of the plaintext. Then each form is separated from each other meaning each one contains a valid button to verify if the encryption was done correctly.

The problem is that when pressing the validate button from the second form and beyond, it always sends the first form information. I noticed this because I'm printing in the Javascript and python the values of the forms and it always prints the first forms.

Template:

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for='id_plaintext'>
    Plaintext:
  </label>
  <form onsubmit="return false;" method="GET">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      {{ formPlaintext.plaintext }}
    </div>
    <button name="action" id="encryptButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="encrypt">Encrypt</button>
  </form>
  <br> {% if formPlaintext.errors %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <strong>{{ formPlaintext.plaintext.errors }}</strong>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>

{% for letterOfWord, keyToUse, letterToFill, letterNumber in equations %}
  <form method="GET" class="form-inline">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">

        <div class="alert alert-info col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
          Excercise Number {{letterNumber}} <br>
          ( {{ letterOfWord }} + {{ keyToUse }} ) mod 26 = {{ letterToFill }}
          <button name="action" class="validate">
            Validate
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="notification">
        {% include "content/caesarValidation.html" %}
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Javascript:

```
   $("#encryptButton").on({
    click: function() {
        var variable = document.getElementById('id_plaintext');
        console.log(variable.value)
        $.ajax({
          url: "/exampleCaesar",
          type: "GET",
          data: {
            CSRF: 'csrf_token',
            plaintext: $('#id_plaintext').val(),
            key: $('#id_key').val()
          },

          success: function(example) {
            $('#example1').show();
            $('#exampleSection').html(example);
            console.log(example);

          }

        }); //END OF Ajax
      } //END OF FUNCTION
  }); //END OF encryptButton

  $(".validate").on({
    click: function(event) {
        var variable = document.getElementById('id_letterToFill');
        console.log(variable.value)
        console.log("Inside validate button function")

        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
          async: true,
          url: "/validateCaesar",
          type: "GET",
          data: {
            CSRF: 'csrf_token',
            originalLetter: $('#id_letterOfWord').val(),
            key: $('#id_keyToUse').val(),
            encryptLetter: $('#id_letterToFill').val(),
            numberLetter : $('#id_letterNumber').val()
          },
          success: function(exampleData) {

            console.log(exampleData)
            $('#notification').html(exampleData)
            console.log(exampleData)

          }

        }); 
      } 
  });
```

Views

```
    def exampleCaesar(request):

    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "GET":
        formKey = caesarKey(request.GET or None)
        formPlaintext = caesarPlaintext(request.GET or None)
        if formKey.is_valid():
            if formPlaintext.is_valid():
                wordToEncrypt = request.GET.get('plaintext')
                wordToEncrypt = wordToEncrypt.upper()
                wordLength = len(request.GET.get('plaintext'))
                key = request.GET.get('key')

                print(wordToEncrypt)
                print(key)
                equations = []
                formKey = caesarKey(request.GET or None)
                letterNumber = 1
                for x in range(wordLength):
                    exampleForm = caesarCipherExample(initial={'letterOfWord' : wordToEncrypt[x], 'keyToUse' : key, 'letterNumber' : letterNumber})
                    # print(exampleForm)
                    if exampleForm.is_valid:
                        equations.append(exampleForm)
                        letterNumber += 1
                        print(equations)

                context = { 'equations' : equations,
                            'formKey' : formKey,
                            'formPlaintext': formPlaintext

                }

                html = render(request, "content/exampleCaesar.html", context)
                return HttpResponse(html)
            else:
                print(formPlaintext.errors)
                context = { 'formKey' : formKey,
                            'formPlaintext': formPlaintext

                }

                html = render(request, "content/exampleCaesar.html", context)
                return HttpResponse(html)


        else:
            print(formKey.errors)

def validateCaesar(request):

    obj = CaesarCipher()
    print("You're in!")

    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'GET':
        formExample = caesarCipherExample(request.GET or None)

        encryptLetter = request.GET.get('encryptLetter').upper()
        originalLetter = request.GET.get('originalLetter')
        key = int(request.GET.get('key'))
        print(encryptLetter)
        print(originalLetter)

        print(key)
        if obj.validateLetter(encryptLetter, originalLetter, key):
            listOfCorrect = [request.GET.get('numberLetter'), 'true']

            print(listOfCorrect)
            html = render(request, "content/caesarValidation.html", {'listOfCorrect' : listOfCorrect})
            return HttpResponse(html)
        else:
            listOfCorrect = [request.GET.get('numberLetter'), 'false']

            print(listOfCorrect)
            html = render(request, "content/caesarValidation.html", {'listOfCorrect' : listOfCorrect})
            return HttpResponse(html)
```

caesarValidation template:

```
   <!doctype html>

{% if listOfCorrect %}
<div id="notification">

{% if "true" in listOfCorrect %}
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    Success!
  </div>

  {% else %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    Fail!
  </div>
{% endif %}

{% endif %}

</div>
```

Here is the forms.py that contains the forms used in the template:

```
class caesarCipherExample(forms.Form):
    letterOfWord = forms.CharField(max_length = 1, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'class' : 'no-border',  'style' : 'width:20px; background-color: #D9EDF7; text-align: left;', 'readonly' : 'readonly'}))
    keyToUse = forms.DecimalField(max_value = 26, min_value = 1, initial = 1, required = True, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'class' : 'no-border', 'style' : 'width:30px; background-color: #D9EDF7; text-align: right;', 'readonly' : 'readonly'}))
    letterToFill = forms.CharField(max_length = 1, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control','style' : 'width:60px'}))
    letterNumber = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'class' : 'no-border',  'style' : 'width:20px; background-color: #D9EDF7; text-align: left;', 'readonly' : 'readonly'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is included multiple times, but each time presumably uses the same ID values for the fields. But in HTML, IDs must be unique.

Rather than getting the field values by ID, you'll need to use jQuery to find the parent form, and get its values from there. Something like:

```
var form = $(this).parent('form');
var variable = form.find('input[name=letterToFill]');
```

and so on for the other values.

Comment: I tried this approach but when trying to print out the variable in Javascript, it is undefined.

Comment: It would help if you showed the included caesarValidation.html template.

Comment: I added the caesarValidation.html template.

Comment: I'm clearly confused. Where are the actual form fields you're trying to validate?

Comment: Just added the forms.py that contains the forms been submitted to the validate.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is all too confusing. Now I don't even understand what form you are talking about; I assumed (perhaps wrongly) you were talking about the second part of that page, which appeared to be including a form in a loop. But now I don't know at all. Maybe you should edit your question, removing everything that is not relevant.

Comment: The for loop includes a list. This list is made up of the caesarCipherExample which contains 4 forms. Each set of forms in the for loop must be submitted individually. Ting is that when I try to submit the second set of forms, it submits the first set.

Comment: But I can't see where you're outputting caesarCipherExample in the template.

Comment: The caesarCipherExample is printed out in the for loop inside the template. How is this done? Simple, the equations list is made up of the caesarCipherExample class which contains the forms.. By made up I mean, the list is composed of each form according to the length of the plaintext. So for example, the word DOG would produce 3 sets of the caesarCipherExample where each set contains the the forms inside the class.